# How do I switch to a different Starter Deck?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015

So, I've started playing with the Green-Blue deck, but I'd like to get the Blue-White one for contrast. How do I unlock that deck in the deckbuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you defeat the final Tutorial level "Test your Skill", you can switch decks. This is a good place to decide if you actually enjoy the deck enough.

After this "trial period", the way you do this (at least in the PC version), is to unlock all the cards for that "Archetype".

So, for example, by unlocking the Green and Black cards that made up the G-B starter deck, I gained access to it as a template. You can unlock the cards via the application of money, or by grinding the "Explore" missions.

Obviously, this doesn't help if your deck is struggling with a particular opponent, but sideboarding cards in to defeat specific match-ups works very well, in some cases giving you a better long-term deck.